# Format Specifier markup in results returned by Google API

Tags: java, eclipse, google-search-api

I am using Google Search API in eclipe follwing [this](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/05/call-google-search-api-in-java-program/) example. The above mentioned example says that it would return results as follows:-

```
total: 4

Title: ProgramCreek.com
URL: http://www.programcreek.com/

Title: Top 8 Diagrams for Understanding Java - ProgramCreek.com
URL: http://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/top-8-diagrams-for-understanding-java/

Title: Top 10 Methods for Java Arrays - ProgramCreek.com
URL: http://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/top-10-methods-for-java-arrays/
```

I used the code and Search for "Car".Code is as follows:-

```
public class TestGoogleSea {  
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,    {
    //     more than 4 results google start here ......................

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i = i + 4) {
        String address = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&start="+i+"&q=";

        String query = "Car";
        String charset = "UTF-8";

        URL url = new URL(address + URLEncoder.encode(query, charset));
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), charset);
        GoogleResults results = new Gson().fromJson(reader, GoogleResults.class);

        // Show title and URL of each results
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);


        for (int m = 0; m <= 3; m++) {

writer.println("----------------------------------------------------------------");
            try {
                System.out.println("Title: " + 
results.getResponseData().getResults().get(m).getTitle());
                System.out.println("URL: " +  
results.getResponseData().getResults().get(m).getUrl() + "\n");
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();                
            }
        }

        writer.println("----------------------------------------------------------------");
        String string = stringWriter.toString();
    }
        //..............google code ends here............................................

} 
}
class GoogleResults{

private ResponseData responseData;
public ResponseData getResponseData() { return responseData; }
public void setResponseData(ResponseData responseData) { this.responseData = responseData; }
public String toString() { return "ResponseData[" + responseData + "]"; }

static class ResponseData {
    private List<Result> results;
    public List<Result> getResults() { return results; }
    public void setResults(List<Result> results) { this.results = results; }
    public String toString() { return "Results[" + results + "]"; }
}

static class Result {
    private String url;
    private String title;
    public String getUrl() { return url; }
    public String getTitle() { return title; }
    public void setUrl(String url) { this.url = url; }
    public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }
    public String toString() { return "Result[url:" + url +",title:" + title + "]"; }
}

}
```

I am facing two problems.***Firstly***,  Search results from within eclipe are quiet different from direct search in google browser (I tried www.google.com/ncr too but no luck). ***Secondly***,my results are lousy. As shown below, with unwanted characters in the titles:-

```
Title: New <b>Cars</b>, Used <b>Cars</b>, <b>Car</b> Reviews | <b>Cars</b>.com
URL: http://www.cars.com/  

Title: <b>CALIFORNIA ASSOCIATION OF REALTORS</b>® - www.<b>car</b>.org  
URL: http://www.car.org/  

Title: Automobile - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia  
URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automobile  

Title: New <b>Cars</b>, Used <b>Cars</b> - Find <b>Cars</b> for Sale and Reviews at <b>...</b>  
URL: http://www.autotrader.com/

Title: <b>Car</b> Tech - CNET - CNET.com  
URL: http://www.cnet.com/topics/car-tech/  

Title: New <b>Car</b> Quotes, Buy Used <b>Cars</b>, and Prices | The <b>cars</b>.com <b>...</b>  
URL: http://www.car.com/

Title: <b>Car</b> Reviews - New <b>Cars</b> for 2014 and 2015 at <b>Car</b> and Driver
URL: http://www.caranddriver.com/

Title: CarMax - Browse used <b>cars</b> and new <b>cars</b> online
URL: http://www.carmax.com/

Title: <b>Car</b> Buying - Edmunds.com
URL: http://www.edmunds.com/car-buying/

Title: <b>Car</b> Tips &amp; Expert Advice for <b>Cars</b>, Trucks &amp; SUVs | Edmunds.com
URL: http://www.edmunds.com/cars/

Title: New <b>Cars</b> - Compare New <b>Car</b> Prices and Vehicles for Sale <b>...</b> 
URL: http://www.edmunds.com/new-cars/

Title: HowStuffWorks &quot;How <b>Cars</b> Work&quot;
URL: http://auto.howstuffworks.com/car.htm

Title: <b>Cars</b> (2006) - IMDb
URL: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0317219/

Title: What&#39;s My <b>Car</b> Worth - Blue Book Used <b>Car</b> &amp; Trade-In Values <b>...</b> 
URL: http://www.kbb.com/whats-my-car-worth/

Title: I-<b>CAR</b> - Education, Knowledge and Solutions for Collision Repair <b>...</b>
URL: https://www.i-car.com/

Title: Thrifty <b>Car</b> Rental
URL: http://www.thrifty.com/

Title: New <b>Cars</b> &amp; New <b>Car</b> Prices - Kelley Blue Book
URL: http://www.kbb.com/new-cars/

Title: Enterprise Rent-A-<b>Car</b> - Rental <b>Cars</b> at Low, Affordable Rates
URL: http://www.enterprise.com/car_rental/home.do

Title: SFGate Local Marketplace | New and Used <b>Cars</b> in San Francisco <b>...</b>
URL: http://cars.sfgate.com/

Title: Avis <b>Car</b> Rental - Rent A <b>Car</b> with Avis
URL: http://www.avis.com/
```

What am i doing wrong? and how could this be rectified. thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks a lot like you're picking up on the advertisements that appear in the search results.

Comment: I have placed code that i used and the complete result returned in the console.

Comment: @APerson: Is there any way to get rid of the ads?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue, if you look in the actual Json file (paste the URL into your browser is easiest) you'll notice that there is a title and a titleNoFormatting.

The simplest solution is just to change wherever title is mentioned to titleNoFormatting in the GoogleResults Result static class.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. can you please mention exactly where in code titleNoFormatting to use. Couldnt get code example on net yet.